# Copy from dynamodb to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a dynamodb table with approx 10 GB data. I need to dump it to s3 or a data warehouse solution within a span of less than 5 mins. I need to know if theres any solution out there that can make this possible. Or if this is at all possible to do so within 5 mins. Do let me know if anyone has tried this ever.

I have tried to use glue and copying to redshift but without any luck. It takes a lot of time to copy and transfer the data.

Comment: When you say "it takes a lot of time to copy", have you tried increasing the Read Capacity Units to make the table faster to access? You can check in Amazon CloudWatch whether you have hit the limit on read capacity.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did try to increase to RCUs. However, redshift is not able to consume the RCUs to a considerable extent.

Answer (score 0):

10 GB of data to be transferred within 5 minutes equals ~ 33.3MByte per second transfer speed. Piece of cake if you keep the traffic within AWS. Be sure as @JohnRotenstein mentioned to keep the IOPs of the table above this threshhold.

AWS has a tutorial on how to export a DynamoDB Table to S3 using a Data Pipeline:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html

Comment: 33.3MByte per second will require about 4200 provisioned read capacity units. (8k per consumed read capacity unit). On demand billing would work also. Parallel scan will almost certainly be required.